# 'CLLocationManagerDelegate' cannot be constructed because it has no accessible initializers

Tags: swift, cllocationmanager

I am a newbie coder and I am using a tutorial to help me learn.

I am making a weather app, but I am receiving this error and was hoping someone could help.

> 'CLLocationManagerDelegate' cannot be constructed because it has no accessible initializers

[image: 'CLLocationManagerDelegate' cannot be constructed because it has no accessible initializers]

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

`WeatherViewController` is already the `CLLocationManagerDelegate`.

You should be instantiating `CLLocationManager` instead:

```
let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
```

Comment: Thank you! That fixed it